# How to Solve Error 4003 on SSH Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

I want to access to SSH from GCP like as always but Error 4003 appears
[Screenshoots of Error 4003](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbHyi.png)

this is my VPC Firewall
[Screenshoots of VPC Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb2yh.png)

this is my Instance Details

[Screenshoots of instance detail 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNEjz.png)

[Screenshoots of instance detail 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN7da.png)

[Screenshoots of instance detail 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39U3W.png)

this is my IAM
[Screenshoots of IAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEkRp.png)

Comment: Edit your question and show the steps that you have tried (the exact steps) to debug this issue. Remove the links to other resources. We need to see your system's configuration. The most common problems are a) VPC and/or OS firewall rules; b) the system has crashed - reboot it; c) the root file system has run out of space. Show the steps that you used to verify those three items as a start.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for quick reply, i have been edited my thread

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error is about you haven't configured Identity-Aware Proxy on port 22.

Failed to connect to backend

The following errors might occur when you connect to your VM from the Google Cloud Console or the gcloud tool:

```
The Cloud Console:
```

-- Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed

-- Code: 4003

-- Reason: failed to connect to backend

The gcloud tool:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) Error while connecting [4003: u'failed to connect to backend'].
```

These errors occur when you try to use SSH to connect to a VM that doesn't have a public IP address and for which you haven't configured Identity-Aware Proxy on port 22.

To resolve this issue Create a firewall rule on port 22 that allows ingress traffic from Identity-Aware Proxy.

[click here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#failed_to_connect_to_backend) for more information.